# ImageView will not update to display the new image, even though I tell it to

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview, android-bitmap

I have an array of Bitmap images, and when I try to update the ImageView through a function, nothing happens.  When I run this function, I want the ImageView's image to be replaced with the next frame.  The first image always gets set, however, when I run the function again, the image never changes.  Can someone help me out to find where I am going wrong?  Isn't it possible to update the ImageView's picture?  Thank you for the help, here is my code:

```
public void setTheImageView() {

        if (videoPreview.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
            Log.e("IF", "If statement reached");
            videoPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imagePreview.setImageBitmap(framesArray.get(countFrame));
            imagePreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            Log.e("ELSE", "Else statement reached");
            imagePreview.setImageBitmap(framesArray.get(countFrame));
        }
        countFrame++;
        Log.e("FRAME", "the count frame is at " + countFrame);

    }
```

Everything else is running correctly, the countFrame variable is changing, and the proper if and else statements are being reached.

Comment: how you are updating the image..after first image is displayed..you are calling setTheImageView() method again..in some loop...or after some time..

Comment: Where do you call set TheImageView?

Comment: show where you use `setTheImageView`. Is it called from Ui thread?

Comment: I am going to eventually call the new image after sometime, however, I am simply trying to test it now to make sure I can change the image.  Once I figure that out I will write a function that changes the image after a certain number of milliseconds.  And yes this is being called from the UI thread.

Comment: Figured it out.  It had nothing to do with setting the ImageView, but I was gathering my images from a video with the method `dataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(time)` and was passing in a value for milliseconds, but it actually requires microseconds.